# Symfony 2 error with parameter session_time in parameters

Tags: symfony

I got an error when started an old project based on symfony 2.

> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]
>   You have requested a non-existent parameter "session_time". Did you mean this: "session_id"?

In `parameters.ini` I haven't session_time, but in `config.yml`:

```
pdo.db_options:
    db_table:    session
    db_id_col:   session_id
    db_data_col: session_value
    db_time_col: session_time
```

Can you help me please to resolve it?

Comment: Missing session table? https://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/configuration/pdo_session_storage.html

Comment: @AndreaManzi ok, thanx. I have already added table but the same.

Comment: Please post all config.yml

Comment: @AndreaManzi, resolved https://stackoverflow.com/a/57853481/6469558, thanx a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to follow this instructions [symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/2.4/cookbook/configuration/pdo_session_storage.html#mysql)

And after, you need to add configuration to your `parameters.ini`, for example:

```
session_time="3600"
```